# Javascript Barcode/OCR reader for PDF-417 format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ocr, barcode-scanner, pdf417

I am trying to implement a javascript/react code to scan barcode of PDF-417 format. I havent done this before. On researching I found:

https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/js-zxing-pdf417 based on https://github.com/zxing/zxing, but it seems to be working only with the image provided.. other barcode images seems to be failing.

Basically I need to take user input from laptop camera and scan the barcode and read the data.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can try the [online demo](https://demo.dynamsoft.com/dbr_wasm/barcode_reader_javascript.html) to scan your barcode images. If it can work, you can use it via npm command `npm i dynamsoft-javascript-barcode`.

Comment: Hi @yushulx thank you for your response. This is a paid library. I am looking for an open-source solution for this problem. Would you know any open source solution?

Comment: ZXing and ZBar are probably the most-welcomed open-source barcode SDKs. However, the defects of the open-source projects are there is no algorithm improvement. When you find the SDK failed to decode barcodes, you have three options: 1. improve the image quality. 2. improve the algorithm. 3. find a new SDK.